# CKEditor and Poltergeist/PhantomJS - [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "default" was not found at "http://cdn.ckeditor.com

Tags: ckeditor, phantomjs, poltergeist

`[CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "default" was not found at "http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/full/styles.js?t=F0RD".`

I intermittently run into this error while running integration tests in Poltergeist. While researching the issue I've seen some older threads with this problem related to actual missing assets, but the library is being loaded from the CDN so I have no control over the assets.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This solved in my case:

```
page.execute_script <<-SCRIPT
  var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/assets/ckeditor/';
SCRIPT
```

Comment: What context did you do this in? What file is that line of code in?